# If you exceed the maximum recommended title length does Google still use those keywords for ranking?

Tags: google, penalty, title-attribute

I know there is a maximum recommended title length because Google cuts off after 600px so there is a rough character count of 60 characters which Moz says catches 90% of titles.

I am aware of the potential click through rate damage because the title is cut off, but has Google ever indicated that it doesn't take the cut off part into account when ranking for the keywords?  i.e. does Google still say "the page title helps me to decide what the page is about"?

I assume there is no direct penalty for a longer title, but missing out on some parts could help decide keyword placement.

I'm sure this has been asked before but I couldn't find it.  And Stack says this is subjective but I can't think of an objective way to ask it.

Comment: First things first. Search is not about keywords. Never has been with Google. So please stop thinking in these terms. Also, please consider the title tag length limitation is limited to the SERP link. Full stop. Title tags are taken whole otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Google rewrites titles when required from content on your page... if your missing a keyword in the title it can easily rewrite your title and include it, as done with most searches these days.

Google will and regularly rewrites both
`<title>` and `<meta name="description">` to match the search of the user,  it does this by extracting relevant parts of the page, therefore there's no need to 'keyword stuff' or worry about titles being the perfect length.

Various online case studies have displayed that sites using **meaningful titles** have the best click rates which in turn can increase the rankings of the entire site due to the fact more visitors equals chances for gaining natural SEO from backlinks and social buzz.

*Example*

- Good title: `How to design a website in under 59mins`
- Great title: `How to design a HTML5 website in under 59mins`
- Poor title: `How to design a website in under 59mins using HTML5, PHP, MySQL and WordPress`
- Horrid title `How to design a website using HTML5, PHP, MySQL, WordPress and Photoshop`

I'm not saying not to use long titles because they are perfectly fine too, even this page as you can see has a long title, but its also not stuffed with keywords.

*Summary*

A great title is made up of the most important keywords on the page and gets users clicking it, almost like a subliminal message.

*Question Answer*

Both Google and Bing do not punish for long titles, long titles become noise and may be ignored completely which means they will use other page signals. If you write hundreds or thousands of pages in this manner then it could become a penalty due to keyword stuffing, which still happens but far less and you need to be extremely aggressive for either to take notice.

Comment: It's not so much about me wanting to partake in keyword stuffing, it's more about some pages are generated from the title of the article or product.  In which case the title is sometimes long.  It's a normal title and readers wouldn't be offended, however, I was concerned that if the title was something along the lines of `would you be fantastically interested in understanding the art of designing a website` (made up title) would lose the main keywords as they are at the end.  In which case we could artificially rewrite the title to be better suited.

Comment: Keywords are okay on the end... just make them at the end of the world like in your example.

Comment: did you mean just don't make them?

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to keep it short.

Yes

Google still reads the rest of your title past 512px limit. So no matter how long your title is, Google will read it.